# Getting java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.reflection.ReflectionHelper.makeMe

Tags: java, rest, maven, jersey, tomcat7

I am facing troubles in exposing RESTful Api from my application.
The application is based on `java8` with `Tomcat7` and `Jersey2` is used for exposing RESTful api.

For the moment, the code is quite easy, but still does not work.
When I try to deploy the application on the server I get the following stacktrace:

```
Jun 08, 2017 3:02:06 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
SEVERE: StandardWrapper.Throwable
MultiException stack 1 of 2
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.reflection.ReflectionHelper.makeMe(Ljava/lang/reflect/Constructor;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.createMe(ClazzCreator.java:244)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.create(ClazzCreator.java:319)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.create(SystemDescriptor.java:448)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SingletonContext.findOrCreate(SingletonContext.java:107)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.createService(Utilities.java:2203)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.getService(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:579)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.getService(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:566)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.ServiceLocatorUtilities.enablePerThreadScope(ServiceLocatorUtilities.java:86)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.Injections._createLocator(Injections.java:144)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.Injections.createLocator(Injections.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.<init>(ApplicationHandler.java:265)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.<init>(WebComponent.java:262)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:167)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:349)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1280)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1088)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5176)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5460)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
MultiException stack 2 of 2
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to perform operation: create on org.jvnet.hk2.internal.DynamicConfigurationServiceImpl
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.create(ClazzCreator.java:346)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.create(SystemDescriptor.java:448)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SingletonContext.findOrCreate(SingletonContext.java:107)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.createService(Utilities.java:2203)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.getService(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:579)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.getService(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:566)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.ServiceLocatorUtilities.enablePerThreadScope(ServiceLocatorUtilities.java:86)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.Injections._createLocator(Injections.java:144)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.Injections.createLocator(Injections.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.<init>(ApplicationHandler.java:265)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.<init>(WebComponent.java:262)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:167)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:349)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1280)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1088)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5176)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5460)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Jun 08, 2017 3:02:06 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext loadOnStartup
SEVERE: Servlet /SmartFabConnector threw load() exception
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.reflection.ReflectionHelper.makeMe(Ljava/lang/reflect/Constructor;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.createMe(ClazzCreator.java:244)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.create(ClazzCreator.java:319)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.create(SystemDescriptor.java:448)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SingletonContext.findOrCreate(SingletonContext.java:107)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.createService(Utilities.java:2203)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.getService(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:579)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.getService(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:566)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.ServiceLocatorUtilities.enablePerThreadScope(ServiceLocatorUtilities.java:86)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.Injections._createLocator(Injections.java:144)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.Injections.createLocator(Injections.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.<init>(ApplicationHandler.java:265)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.<init>(WebComponent.java:262)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:167)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:349)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1280)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1088)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5176)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5460)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

This is my `pom.xml`:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>SmartFabConnector</groupId>
  <artifactId>SmartFabConnector</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <name>SmartFabConnector</name>
  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <resources>
      <resource>
        <directory>src</directory>
        <excludes>
          <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
        </excludes>
      </resource>
    </resources>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.5.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.8</source>
          <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
        <configuration>
          <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  <repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>maven2-repository.java.net</id>
        <name>Java.net Repository for Maven</name>
        <url>http://download.java.net/maven/2/</url>
        <layout>default</layout>
    </repository>
  </repositories>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.13</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.jersey.core/jersey-common -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-common</artifactId>
        <version>2.13</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.annotation/javax.annotation-api -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.annotation</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.annotation-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.jersey.bundles.repackaged/jersey-guava -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.bundles.repackaged</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-guava</artifactId>
        <version>2.13</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.hk2/hk2-api -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.hk2</groupId>
        <artifactId>hk2-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0-b10</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.hk2/hk2-utils -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.hk2</groupId>
        <artifactId>hk2-utils</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0-b10</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.hk2.external/javax.inject -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.hk2.external</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0-b10</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.hk2.external/aopalliance-repackaged -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.hk2.external</groupId>
        <artifactId>aopalliance-repackaged</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0-b10</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.hk2/hk2-locator -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.hk2</groupId>
        <artifactId>hk2-locator</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0-b10</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.javassist/javassist -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.javassist</groupId>
        <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
        <version>3.18.1-GA</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.hk2/osgi-resource-locator -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.hk2</groupId>
        <artifactId>osgi-resource-locator</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.jersey.core/jersey-server -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
        <version>2.13</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.jersey.core/jersey-client -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
        <version>2.13</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.validation/validation-api -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
        <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.ws.rs/javax.ws.rs-api -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.jersey.containers/jersey-container-servlet -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
        <version>2.13</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

This is my `web.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>SmartFabConnector</display-name>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>MyApplication</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
        <param-value>com.rold.industry.rest.MyApplication</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>MyApplication</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/api/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Then the classes. This is the binder:

```
package com.rold.industry.rest;

import org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.binding.AbstractBinder;

public class RestAppBinder extends AbstractBinder {
    @Override
    protected void configure() {
        bind(RESTful.class).to(RESTful.class);
    }
}
```

This is the Resource Config:

```
package com.rold.industry.rest;

import org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig;

public class MyApplication extends ResourceConfig {
    public MyApplication() {
        register(new RestAppBinder());
        packages(true, "com.rold.industry.rest");
    }
}
```

And this is the class which expose the methods:

```
@Path("RESTfulService")
public class RESTful {

    @GET
    @Path("/Dipendente/{id}")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public String getEmployeeName(@PathParam("id") String id){
        String accessToken = "";
        try {
            accessToken = ApiCaller.getAccessToken();
        } catch (UnirestException e) {
            System.out.println("Errore");
        }
        Unirest.setDefaultHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken);
        Employee employee = EmployeeApi.getInstance().getEmployeeById(new Integer(id));
        return employee.getName();
    }
}
```

Does anybody have clues on what I am doing wrong?
Thanks in advance,
Francesco

Comment: `NoSuchMethodError` leads to incompatible jar files. in your case the jar files which contains `org.jvnet.hk2` and  `org.glassfish.hk2.`

Comment: I don't understand what you mean, because there is no dependency starting with `org.jvnet.hk2.`

Comment: Looks like it is in the `hk2-locator` jar

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you check dependency conflicts before packaging. It's easy to apply in maven projects.
`mvn enforcer:enforce`

Before, add this maven plugin;

```xml
<plugin>
<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-enforcer-plugin</artifactId>
<version>3.0.0-M3</version>
<configuration>
    <rules>
        <dependencyConvergence />
    </rules>
</configuration>
</plugin>
```